# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(Y,d')$ a subspace. Prove that the inclusion map is continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(Y,d')$ a subspace. Prove that the inclusion map $i:Y \to X$ defined by $i(y)=y$, $y \in Y$ is continuous.

For clarification, my textbook defines a subspace of a metric space:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y$ a subset of $X$. The metric space $(Y,d')$, where $d'$ is the restriction of $d$ to $Y\times Y$, is a subspace of $(X,d)$.

No idea how to start, any help appreciated.

Comment: Surely you have *some* idea how to start. What's the definition of a continuous function between two metric spaces?

Comment: I'm working with Croom's Principles of Topology and many definitions for continuous functions are given. Are you referring to a definition involving balls?

Comment: Edited per your suggestion but the problem is entirely ambiguous on which d and d' so it's meant to be for any

Comment: Thanks for responding with your edit.  However the key to this problem lies in knowing the relationship between metrics $d$ and $d'$.  Indicate whether Readers should assume they give the same distances between any pairs of points in $Y$, or if you have some less direct relationship in mind.

Comment: It isn't true for an arbitrary choice of metrics $d$ on $X$ and $d'$ on subset $Y$.

Comment: @hardmath That's a good point. Does $(Y,d')$ count as a subspace of $(X,d)$ if we only have $Y \subseteq X$ but possibly different metrics? I'm not even sure the result is true in that case.

Comment: It's not true.  The identity map from $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric topology to $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology is not continuous.

Comment: Categorically speaking, "subobjects" are usually subsets where the inclusion map is a morphism within that category.  So I believe subsets of a topological space are only considered subspaces under the subspace topology inherited from the ambient space.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang And I assume that for metric spaces, the subobject must inherit the metric, not just the topology, from the ambient space (i.e. an equivalent metric wouldn't qualify)?

Comment: @Bungo Yes, I would assume that too.

Comment: Aha! Now that you added the textbook definition, we see that $d'$ and $d$ are assumed to agree on $Y$, so the result is in fact true, and the answer given by Behnam proves it.

Comment: I apologize, I am very new to topology, I did not know that was relevant

Comment: Understood, no problem. This is a good example of why you should provide context when asking a question, e.g. cite the relevant definitions used by your book and/or lecture. Not every definition is completely standard, and some authors may include implicit assumptions that others don't. Including this context can help avoid confusion (and your question will be less likely to be downvoted or closed!)

Answer (score 0):

Pick any two $y, y' \in Y$ then $$d_X(I(y),I(y')) = d_X(y,y')=d_Y(y,y') \leq 1 * d_Y(y,y')$$
where the first two distances are in the target space $X$, and the last one is understood as distance in the domain space $Y$.

This shows that the map $I$ is 1-lipschitz.

(You can use balls to give an epsilon-delat format argument.)

Comment: You've assumed that $d_X$ and $d_Y$ agree on $Y$, which is probably intended (and necessary) but it isn't stated in the OP.

Comment: Its not stated by me because it's not stated in the textbook or anywhere near the problem. I wish I could give more clarity but this is what I am working with

Comment: Would it be possible to expand on "1-lipschitz" I've never seen that before

Comment: @JessSavoie Can you look up your book's definition of subspace of a metric space and add it to your OP? Maybe there's some language that implies $d = d'$ on $Y$. If not, I have to assume that it's an error/typo in the problem statement.

Comment: I added the books defn

Comment: @JessSavoie Thanks for adding the book's definition - it indeed assumes that the two metrics are assumed to agree on $Y$, so this answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: I am still confused how this solution's conclusion is related to the metrics being continuous

Comment: @JessSavoie If $y$ is close to $y'$ (i.e. $d(y,y')$ is small) then the inequality shows that $I(y)$ will be close to $I(y')$ (because the distance from $I(y)$ to $I(y')$ is $\leq$ the distance from $y$ to $y'$). See if you can convert this informal argument to an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
\begin{align*}
i^{-1}(B_{X}(a,\epsilon))&=\{x\in Y: i(x)\in B(a,\delta)\}\\
&=\{x\in Y: x\in B(a,\epsilon)\}\\
&=\{x\in Y: d(x,a)<\epsilon\}\\
&=\{x\in Y: d'(x,a)<\epsilon\}\\
&=B_{Y}(a,\epsilon).
\end{align*}
And those $B_{X}(a,\epsilon)$ constitute a topological basis for $X$, we are done.